# Last image in image slider jumping on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built an image slider that shows 2 partial images and 1 full image on `mouseenter` of that particular image. It worked fine until I set the last image to its full width (using css) as a default image (this way when the user opens the page this 1 image will show completely).

I have used an `if` statement so the default image is reduced in width when the other images are hovered over. However as soon as any of the images are moused over including the default the last image momentarily reduces its width before the other image expands. This creates a temporary gap on the right side of the slider. I've tried changing the animation times and using other methods like jQuery's `css()` method without any success.

The same problem also occurs on `mouseleave` when it leaves the containing slider from the last "default" image only.

Anyone have any idea on how to overcome this bug so the animation runs smoothly ?

**HTML**

```
<div id='imgSlider'>
    <ul>
        <li><img src='images/Girl-skyscraper.jpg' height='300' width='300' /></li>
        <li><img src='images/cities-skies.jpg' height='300' width='300'/></li>
        <li><img src='images/windows.jpg' height='300' width='300' /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#imgSlider {
    height:300px;
    width:600px;
    border:1px solid #2367d3;
}

div#imgSlider ul li {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div#imgSlider ul li:last-child {
    width:300px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('div#imgSlider ul li').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        if($(this) != $('div#imgSlider ul li:last')) {
            $('div#imgSlider ul li:last').animate({
                width: '150'
            },0);
        } 
        $(this).animate({width:'300'},400);
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'150'},400);
    }
});

$('div#imgSlider').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('div#imgSlider ul li:last').animate({
        width:'300'
    },400);
});
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XwL2G/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle so it's easy to help you.

Comment: jsfiddle added, hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

A different way of doing things, using the same html.

**CSS**

```
#imgSlider{
     position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
}

ul{position:relative;}

li{float:left;}
```

Use javascript to move your ul left and right. Add some logic so when you scroll to the end it loops back to the start or prevent `left` getting any higher than the position of the last slide.

Comment: That solves the `mouseenter` issue, tar. Does the `overflow:hidden` still work because it is inherited by the `li` ?

Comment: Personally I would crop all images to be the same size and dimensions and remove the need for overflow:hidden on the `li` and set a width for the `<img>` in the css